# A name for finite rational numbers

Tags: terminology, rational-numbers

Is there a name for finite rational numbers?

Here is what I mean:

```
3 / 2 = 1.5       - this number is finite
1 / 3 ~ 0.3333... - this number is not finite, it has infinite "3"

I need a term to "catch" the first type of numbers, but not the second.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.

I think you mean **terminating** [decimals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal).

(All rational numbers are finite.  Some have only infinitely long decimal representations, though.)

Comment: +1. As a quick postscript: for base $2$, the analogous term is "dyadic rational," and for base $3$ "triadic rational." While this can of course be continued further on, I've never heard of any others and indeed I think that for arbitrary bases there is no snappy term. However, the phrase "number with terminating base-$k$ expansion" is unambiguous if lengthy.

Comment: According to what you said, my question could (and probably should) be asked in the following way: **Is there a name for rational numbers with terminated decimals**? Of course, we can call them "as is", "rational-numbers-with-terminated-decimals", but it will be better if there exist a shorter common-known term for them.